# how can I shorten my animation?

Tags: jquery

I've the following jquery code:

```
$('#swipe').on('click',function(){
    $('.swipe-1').animate({width:'100%'},1000);
    $('.swipe-2').delay(1000).animate({width:'100%'},1000);
    $('.swipe-3').delay(2000).animate({width:'100%'},1000);
    $('.swipe-4').delay(3000).animate({width:'100%'},1000);
    $('.swipe-5').delay(4000).animate({width:'100%'},1000);
    $('.swipe-6').delay(5000).animate({width:'100%'},1000);
    $('.swipe-7').delay(6000).animate({width:'100%'},1000);
});
```

Can I shorten my above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a common class like `swipe` instead of making 7 different classes:

```
$('#swipe').on('click',function(){
    $('.swipe').each(function(i,v){
        $(this).delay(i*1000).animate({width:'100%'},1000);
    });
});
```

[delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay) may not work here because there is no `queue` of animation, so `setTimeout` is better to use like,

```
$('#swipe').on('click',function(){
    $('.swipe').each(function(i,v){
        var $this=$(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.animate({width:'100%'},1000);
        },(i*1000));
    });
});
```

Comment: then other css like left right values would be go wrong all 7 div has own left and right values

Comment: @C-link each element has its own 100% of widht; how would they interfere?

Comment: each swipe has different css but only width is same

Comment: @C-link you should mention it before. I just answered of `Can I shorten my above code?`

Comment: @C-link ... so? `animate` doesn't touch anything it isn't told to.

Comment: anyway this solution is also acceptable as I have to make selector [class^=swipe] instead of .swipe

Comment: @C-link if you want styling by CSS, you can have two classes. `class = "swipe swipe-1"` - one for javascript, one for styling. Don't pattern-match the `class` attribute.

Comment: @C-link if you can handle delay for every `swipe-*` using `javascript`, then you can handle `left` and `right` positioning also.

Comment: Suppose I just now want to something else after the animation complete I've to calculate each delay and apply for that animation like (0+1000+2000+3000+4000+5000+6000) = 21000 and do like this: .delay(21000).do_something. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Like this ?

```
$('#swipe').on('click',function(){
    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
        $('.swipe-'+(i+1)).delay(i*1000).animate({width:'100%'},1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - Nope, zero! It's a nifty trick to get zero delay on the first iteration.

Comment: Oh, you just answered your own question…

Comment: @Luxelin ... and apparently someonne else found the OP's question boring and his solution good.

Comment: @adeneo then how could he gets the delay of 1000 in first iteration?

Comment: There is no delay in the first iteration

Comment: @AnoopJoshi he doesn't need delay for the 1st.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi um, `.delay((i-1)*1000)` (if you want to start with `i=1`)

Comment: But it goes a little to far, `i<8` means it stops at `7`, but then in the selector there's `i+1`, so it would look for `.swipe-8` as well? Should be `i<7`

Comment: And the delay in the question is not consistent, suddenly it jumps 2000, which this answer doesn't

Comment: @adeneo hmm... it looks like a mistake in the question; the gap doesn't seem deliberate.