# How to combine jQuery functions into smaller scripts

Tags: jquery, dry

I'm still learning jQuery, and the biggest issue I'm having is how to take several smaller sections of code and combine them into a much more efficient script.

For example, I have a gallery of 7 items, and every item fades in, but with a different delay. (So image number 1 fades in after 1 second, image number 2 after 1.5, image number 3 after half a second etc) so that they do not all fade in at the same time. See the second section [here](http://www.francesca-designed.me/negozio/).

The problem is, my code ends up quite long as I'm repeating the same code but with a different delay and targeting a different div. I need advice on how to make this more efficient. E.g:

```
$( ".gal:first-child" ).delay(800).animate({
    opacity:1
  }, 1800, function() {
  });

  $( ".gal:nth-child(2)" ).delay(2000).animate({
    opacity:1
  }, 1800, function() {
  });

  $( ".gal:nth-child(3)" ).delay(800).animate({
    opacity:1
  }, 1800, function() {
  });

  $( ".gal:nth-child(4)" ).delay(1500).animate({
    opacity:1
  }, 1800, function() {
  });

   $( ".gal:nth-child(5)" ).delay(800).animate({
    opacity:1
  }, 1800, function() {
  });

    $( ".gal:nth-child(6)" ).delay(1900).animate({
    opacity:1
  }, 1800, function() {
  });

     $( ".gal:last-child" ).delay(1500).animate({
    opacity:1
  }, 1800, function() {
  });
```

1. How would you make this more efficient?
2. Would randomising the delay between two set values help?
3. How would you ensure all the divs in the gallery get selected? (Randomise nth-child 1-7 maybe?)

Comment: Is there a pattern? Is the number off milliseconds' delay relative to the index of each element?

Comment: @oGeez no pattern, in fact I'm trying to make it fairly "random" as I do not want them to fade in in a sequence, I want it to look a little more fluid.

Comment: possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827790/how-can-i-shorten-my-animation/22827811#22827811)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a property in your HTML tags, like data-delay.
Sample HTML:

```
<div class="gal" data-delay="1000">
  I will show up after 1000 ms
</div>
```

You can now do this:

```
$(".gal").each(function() {
  $(this).delay(+$(this).data("delay"))
         .animate({ opacity: 1 }, function() {});
});
```

Of course, you can use random, but I think that JS should do very few things. The delay can be calculated on the server.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a really nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to give them random delays up to 5 seconds:

```
$(".gal").each(function() {
    var delay = Math.random()*5000;
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1800, function() {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see any pattern in the numbers you can use an array like

```
var $els = $(".gal");
$.each([800, 2000, 800, 1500, 800, 1900, 1500], function (i, val) {
    $els.filter(':nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').delay(val).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1800, function () {});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    var count =0; 
    $(".gal").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(++count*500).animate({ opacity: 1 },1800, function() {

        });
    });
```

Comment: It's already been mentioned that the delays are not relative to the index; they are closer to random.

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this:

```
var arr = [800,2000,800,1500,800,1900,1500];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
$( ".gal" ).delay(arr[i]).animate({
    opacity:1
  }, 1800, function() {
  });
}
```

But I would recommend you to use data like @Silviu Burcea answered.